# Fast Report - database record line too long

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Dont know how to put this: I placed a database field on my report. However the text is too long. How can I make it go under? I know there's a setting for this but cant find it.

design time:

[image: design]

runtime:

[image]

Fast report is the 4.13 version.

Comment: I'm sure there's some sort of word wrap option?

Comment: I have wordwrap=true but it still wont go to second line.

Comment: Then this is either a bug in the FastReports or you have mistaken the control with this property for another control. I don't use FastReports, so I don't know.

Comment: In older version I think there was a carriage return option, here it seem to be missing.

Comment: Based on the first screenshot it doesn't appear that we can see the right side of the box.  It must be way out to the right.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set option AutoWidth to false

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you need to do is to shrink the field with the mouse with word wrap on.Funny ...

Comment: You had to make it *smaller* to fit?

Comment: There is the `WordWrap` property, which you can set to True (which is by default) to let the text be wrapped.

Comment: That's the only thing I did. Shrinked with the mouse the field and all of a sudden it split the line into two. Why it wouldnt do in the first place,I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on screenshot, width of frmMemo for database field is bigger then column's width. set it's size same with column's size
2. Set option streched, wordwrap to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You have possible property Clipped = false.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.